# Добавить параметры в js метод

Tags: javascript

Есть метод, выглядит так -

```
spaceParams(space) {
    return Ext.apply({
      space: space
    }, this.up('database-tab').params);
  },
```

здесь мы вызываем метод и добавляем новое поле space, со значением space, затем далее я использую этот метод чтобы передать основный параметры, а так же только что сделанное поле space -

```
dispatch('space.truncate',this.spaceParams(space)
```

но мне нужно чтобы добавлялось не только свойство space, но и свойство index
и это нужно делать точно не в коде выше, потому что тогда метод переопределяется и получается ошибка. Потому что если я например вот так дополняю метод

```
spaceParams(space,index) {
    return Ext.apply({
      space: space,
      index: index
    }, this.up('database-tab').params);
  },
```

то перестают работать некоторые функции (видимо потому что этот метод только с параметром space вызывается еще в некоторых местах)
как добавить эти свойства не в самом методе в начале, а в другом месте кода при вызове метода?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете подавать в функцию любое количество аргументов в любой момент времени.

[arguments | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

```js
function func1(a) {
  console.log(a, arguments);
}

func1(1, 2, 3);
func1();
```

Comment: Проблема немного не в этом, у меня есть метод spaceParams, который мне собирает важные параметры о сессии типа имени сокета, хоста и т.д,
а мне в этот метод нужно еще добавить 1 поле index
вверху уже реализована механика добавления поля space, а нужно еще добавить поле index